# How to get an array of parameters with rclcpp

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent, rosparam, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1, you could [retrieve a list of parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists)

The documentation shows [get_parameter returning an ParameterVariant](http://docs.ros2.org/ardent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#adb7c3b1a45898860713d4f7e892a5fe7) but [ParameterVariant](http://docs.ros2.org/ardent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1parameter_1_1_parameter_variant.html) doesn't seem to have an `as_vector` option.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295518/how-to-get-an-array-of-parameters-with-rclcpp/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-06-27**:
Do you want a list of parameters in a certain namespace, like `/ns/*` -> `['value of /ns/foo', 'value of /ns/bar', 'value of /ns/baz']`, or do you want one parameter as a vector (e.g. parameter `/position` -> `[1.0, 1.0, 0.0]`)?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-06-27**:
The latter, one parameter name, which is why I figured `get_parameters` wouldn't work.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-06-27**:
We may not have that API yet, but we can certainly add it or whatever the appropriate alternative is. There was some work done on lists in parameters this cycle, but I don't know the state off-hand, let me look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the slightly different case than what @tfoote linked to, here's how to get a single parameter as an array of values.

---

We recently merged this feature (made by @ayrton04), see:

- https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/443
- https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/pull/32

Looks like there's no documentation yet, but there is an example of setting:

https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/03ee0e0963ecb0990742eaeee22b334c11b16722/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/set_and_get_parameters.cpp#L47-L48

And you can use `get_parameter(s)` to get the `rclcpp::Parameter` for it, and on that class there are `as_*_array()` methods:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/a49281cff3082410621aeea388944b35ba63f819/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/parameter.hpp#L95-L113

Which return `vector<T>`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on 2020-12-02**:
Is there a way to achieve this by just using `this->declare_parameter<float>("foo", 15.0); this->get_parameter("foo", foo);` syntax? Or in this example how come that the parameter doesn't need to be declared? From reading a long issue involving some 2 booleans with undeclared_auto_param_something_something and another boolean I just got that you always should declare your params, but this example doesn't do that? And is the documentation 2years later still missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's `get_parameters()` [one line above](http://docs.ros2.org/ardent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#a50064d992be50ad8e2ca906d9490c780) which takes a vector of names and returns a vector of ParameterVariants

Edit:

Sorry I thought you wanted to list multiple parameters. We also support arrays of primatives. It looks like the documentation is not complete.

The ParameterVarient includes [ARRAY types natively](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/a49281cff3082410621aeea388944b35ba63f819/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/parameter_value.hpp#L31)

The `get_value` method on the variant will return the vector value. We don't have it in the demos but there are tests covering it you can use as an example, [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/a49281cff3082410621aeea388944b35ba63f819/rclcpp/test/test_parameter.cpp#L630)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1